# Creating packages for PiW and Pi4

Tags: debian, packages

I've set up my own package repository and have published a .deb package to it using *reprepo*. The code was cross-compiled for Raspberry Pi4 on an Ubuntu x86-64 machine using CMake and CPack. That much works. But it doesn't work on a PiW and fails with an `Illegal instruction`, as expected.

When I look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` the sources listed appear to be the same for a PiW and a Pi4,
e.g. `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi`

So how do I create my own .deb packages that work on both PiW and Pi3/4?

Comment: I believe you will need to compile a separate version for the PiW.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Agreed, but then how do I package it so that it works on both PiW and Pi3/4?

Comment: You will have two different packages based on the architecture and depending on how you created your apt repo may have to make changes there as well. If is kind of like i386 and x64.

Comment: @SteveRobillard and what's the magic in `sources.list` that determines which one PiW vs Pi3/4 pulls down? Architecture is 'armhf' for both but 'ARMv6' and 'ARMv7' are different. How do the Rpi deb packages manage with just one?

Comment: I'm vamping a little here, but it probably depends on having a compiler target that works for both (armv6).  Perhaps targeting the PiW with the compiler (which you didn't specify here, we can assume GCC) will execute correctly on both the W and the 4.

Comment: Part of the magic is the package name and the rest is the repo structure, you can have separate repos or separate directories if you want to have a single repo. Debian and Ubuntu have some good documentation on this - as well as what you can find via google.